# AJAX no se trae un escrito con parrafos correctamente

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo el siguiente codigo en un Crud, el Crud posee el siguiente el cual consiste en una pagina HTML que llama a un modal llamado editClass

```
<html lang="es" ng-app>
    <head>
        <!--  Require Gobal -->
        <?php require("../require/head.require.php"); ?>
        <!-- CSS -->
        <?php require("../require/css.require.php"); ?>
        <?php require("../require/insidecss.require.php"); ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--  Require Variables -->
        <?php require("../require/get.require.php"); ?>
        <?php require("../require/function.require.php"); ?>
        

        <!--  GLobal -->
        <div class="page-wrap"> 
          <!--  Menu -->
            <?php require("../require/menu.require.php"); ?>

            <div class="container-fluid padding-container">            
            <!-- Breadcrumb -->
            <?php require("../require/breadcrumb.php"); ?>

            <div class="loader" id="loader">Loading...</div>

            <!-- Border General -->
                <div class="border-1-oscuro padding-10" id="content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <!-- Menu -->
                    
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="" method="post" name="filter" id="filter">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Buscar Centro por Nombre" autocomplete="off">
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <a class="btn btn-outline-success float-right" id="addClase" name="addClase" href="caddclase.php">Añadir Clase</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                
                
                        <div class="tab-content col-md-12" id="myTabContent"> 
                            <div class="tab-pane fade show active table-responsive" id="lista" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="dia-tab">
                                <!--Aca va la tabla de visualizacion de usuarios -->                   
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          
        </div>

        <!--  Footer -->
        <?php require("../require/footer.require.php"); ?>

        <!--  Modal -->
        <?php 
            $modal = 'editClase';
            require("../require/modal.require.php"); 
        ?>
        
        <!-- JS -->
        <?php require("../require/js.require.php"); ?>
        <?php require("../require/insidejs.require.php"); ?>
```

Este es el código HTML del modal

```
<!-- Modal edicion de clase -->
<div class="modal fade" id="editarClase">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">  
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Edición de Clase</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" id="close" name="close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="formPaddign" id="formEditClase" autocomplete="off">
                    <div id="result"></div>
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input hidden id="Id_clase" name="Id_clase"/>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Nombre de la clase <span style="color: #ff0000">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Nombre_clase" id="Nombre_clase" required="required">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group"> 
                                    <label>Tipo de Programa<span style="color: #ff0000">*</span></label>
                                        <select class="form-control form-control-dropdown form-control-dropdown-bb" id="Id_programa" name="Id_programa" required>   
                                            <option selected style="display: none;" id="Id_programa_actual" name="Id_programa_actual">Seleccione un Tipo de Programa</option>
                                            <?php foreach($programasList as $resultadoPrograma):?>
                                                <option value="<?php echo $resultadoPrograma['id_programa']?>"><?php echo $resultadoPrograma['nombre_programa']?>
                                                </option>
                                            <?php endforeach;?>
                                        </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Tipo de servicio <span style="color: #ff0000">*</span></label>
                                    <select class="form-control form-control-dropdown form-control-dropdown-bb" id="Id_servicio" name="Id_servicio" required="required" onchange="seleccionarCategoriaServicio2(); seleccionarAlcanceServicio()">   
                                        <option selected style="display: none;" id="Id_servicio_actual" name="Id_servicio_actual">Seleccione un tipo de servicio</option>
                                            <?php foreach($serviciosList as $resultadoServicio):?>
                                                <option value="<?php echo $resultadoServicio['id_servicio']?>"><?php echo $resultadoServicio['nombre_servicio']?></option>
                                            <?php endforeach;?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Categoría del servicio <span style="color: #ff0000">*</span></label>
                                    <select class="form-control form-control-dropdown form-control-dropdown-bb" name="Id_categoria" id="Id_categoria" required="required" onchange="seleccionarSubcategoriaServicio()">
                                        <option selected style="display: none;" id="Id_categoria_actual" name="Id_categoria_actual">Selecciona una Categoria de Servicio</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Subcategoría del servicio <span style="color: #ff0000">*</span></label>
                                    <select class="form-control form-control-dropdown form-control-dropdown-bb" name="Id_subcategoria" id="Id_subcategoria" required="required">
                                        <option selected style="display: none;" id="Id_subcategoria_actual" name="Id_subcategoria_actual">Selecciona una Subcategoria de Servicio</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Alcance <span style="color: #ff0000">*</span></label>
                                    <select class="form-control form-control-dropdown form-control-dropdown-bb" name="Id_alcance" id="Id_alcance" required="required">
                                        <option selected style="display: none;" id="Id_alcance_actual" name="Id_alcance_actual">Selecciona un Alcance de Servicio</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Nivel <span style="color: #ff0000">*</span></label>
                                    <select class="form-control form-control-dropdown form-control-dropdown-bb" id="Id_nivel" name="Id_nivel" required="required">   
                                        <option selected style="display: none;" id="Id_nivel_actual" name="Id_nivel_actual">Seleccione un Nivel</option>
                                            <?php foreach($nivelList as $resultadoNivel):?>
                                                <option value="<?php echo $resultadoNivel['id_nivel']?>"><?php echo $resultadoNivel['nombre_nivel']?></option>
                                            <?php endforeach;?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Metas <span style="color: #ff0000">*</span></label>
                                    <select class="form-control form-control-dropdown form-control-dropdown-bb" id="Id_metas" name="Id_metas" required="required">   
                                        <option selected style="display: none;" id="Id_metas_actual" name="Id_metas_actual">Seleccione una Meta</option>
                                            <?php foreach($metasList as $resultadoMetas):?>
                                                <option value="<?php echo $resultadoMetas['id_metas']?>"><?php echo $resultadoMetas['nombre_metas']?></option>
                                            <?php endforeach;?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Duración de la clase<span style="color: #ff0000">*</span></label>
                                    <select class="form-control form-control-dropdown form-control-dropdown-bb" name="Duracion_clase" id="Duracion_clase">
                                        <option selected style="display: none;" value="" id="Duracion_clase_actual" name="Duracion_clase_actual">Selecciona...</option>
                                        <option value="0">Indefinido</option>
                                        <?php
                                            $Hora_inicio_f = date('00:00');
                                            $minutos = 0;
                                            for($i = 0; $i <= 60; $i++){
                                                $minutos = $minutos + 5;
                                                $labelMinutos = $minutos.' Minutos';
                                                $Nueva_hora_inicio_f = strtotime ('+5 minutes', strtotime ($Hora_inicio_f)) ;
                                                $Nueva_hora_inicio_f = date ('H:i', $Nueva_hora_inicio_f);
                                                $Hora_inicio_f = $Nueva_hora_inicio_f;
                                                echo '<option value="'.$Nueva_hora_inicio_f.'">'.$labelMinutos.'</option>';
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>                                                                                                           
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Descripción <span style="color: #ff0000">*</span></label>
                                    <textarea name="Descripcion" id="Descripcion" class="form-control" required="required"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-center">
                                <input type="submit" role="button" Id="Guardar" name="Guardar" class="btn btn-secondary btn-verde"  value="Actualizar"/>
                            </div>     

                        </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

¿Cuál es el problema? El problema es que cuando le doy click al botón de editar y hago  que corra mostrarEditClase(), si la descripción posee parrafos y está guardada en la base de datos, los datos se rompen y no los muestra y tira un error de un "" que no se puede evitar. La descripción se guarda en formato texto en la base de datos si preguntan. Me dí cuenta que ocurre con

Aqui muestro el método para mostrar los datos en el modal. Yo supongo que el problema está aquí especificamente por el método de split

```
function mostrarEditClase(datos){

                console.log(datos);

                var d=datos.split("*");

               
                $("#Id_clase").val(d[0]);

                $("#Nombre_clase").val(d[9]);

                $("#Id_programa_actual").val(d[1]);
                document.getElementById("Id_programa_actual").innerText = d[11];

                $("#Id_servicio_actual").val(d[2]);
                document.getElementById("Id_servicio_actual").innerText = d[12];

                $("#Id_categoria_actual").val(d[3]);
                document.getElementById("Id_categoria_actual").innerText = d[13];

                $("#Id_subcategoria_actual").val(d[4]);
                document.getElementById("Id_subcategoria_actual").innerText = d[14];

                $("#Id_metas_actual").val(d[7]);
                document.getElementById("Id_metas_actual").innerText = d[15];

                $("#Id_nivel_actual").val(d[6]);
                document.getElementById("Id_nivel_actual").innerText = d[16];

                $("#Id_alcance_actual").val(d[5]);
                document.getElementById("Id_alcance_actual").innerText = d[17];

                Duracion = moment.duration(d[18]).asMinutes();

                Duracion += " Minutos";

                $("#Duracion_clase_actual").val(d[9]);
                document.getElementById("Duracion_clase_actual").innerText = Duracion; 

                $("#Descripcion").val(d[10]);  

            
                
            }
```

El método usado para traerse los datos de la base de datos es el siguiente

```
function mostrarClases(){

                datos = { 
                    "opcion"  : "mostrarClases",
                    "search": $('#search').val()
                    
                };
                console.log(datos);
                      
                $.ajax({
                    url:'../controllers/clasesController.php',
                    type:'POST',
                    data: datos
                    
                }).done(function(response){

                    var data = JSON.parse(response).respuesta;
                    var msj = JSON.parse(response).msj;
                    var success = JSON.parse(response).success; 


                    html="<table class='table table-bordered table-hover'><thead><tr><td><strong>Nombre clase</strong></td><td><strong>Tipo de servicio</strong></td><td><strong>Tipo de programa</strong></td><td><strong>Editar</strong></td><td><strong>Activo</strong></td></tr></thead><tbody>";
            

                    if(success){

                        var valores = eval(data);

                        for(i=0;i<valores.length;i++){

                            datos=valores[i][0]+"*"+valores[i][1]+"*"+valores[i][2]+"*"+valores[i][3]+"*"+valores[i][4]+"*"+valores[i][5]+"*"+valores[i][6]+"*"+valores[i][7]+"*"+valores[i][8]+"*"+valores[i][9]+"*"+valores[i][10]+"*"+valores[i][11]+"*"+valores[i][12]+"*"+valores[i][13]+"*"+valores[i][14]+"*"+valores[i][15]+"*"+valores[i][16]+"*"+valores[i][17]+"*"+valores[i][18];

                            html+="<tr><td>"+valores[i][9]+"</td><td>"+valores[i][12]+"</td><td>"+valores[i][11]+"</td><td><i id='edit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editarClase' style='cursor:pointer;' onclick='mostrarEditClase("+'"'+datos+'"'+");' class='fa fa-cog' aria-hidden='true'></i></td>";

                            if(valores[i][8] == 1){

                                html+='<td><div class="checkbox"><label style="padding-right: 30px;"><input type="checkbox" name="Estado" id="Estado'+valores[i][0]+'" onclick="cambiarEstado('+valores[i][0]+')" checked></label></div></td>';

                            }else if (valores[i][8] == 2 ){

                                html+='<td><div class="checkbox"><label style="padding-right: 30px;"><input type="checkbox" name="Estado" id="Estado'+valores[i][0]+'" onclick="cambiarEstado('+valores[i][0]+')"></label></div></td>';
                            }
                                
                        }

                        html+="</tbody></table>"

                        $("#lista").html(html);

                    }else{

                        html+="<tr><td colspan='6'>"+msj+"</td></tr></tbody></table>"

                        $("#lista").html(html);
                    }

                    $("#loader").css("display", "none");
                    $("#content").css("display", "block");   
                            
                });
                        
                                   
            }
```

Aquí está el codigo en clasesController, el cual se trae los datos de la base de datos. Voy a dejar el método de como se los trae por si acaso resulta útil para encontrar la solución

```
if($opcion == 'mostrarClases'){ 

    foreach ($_POST as $nombre => $valor) {

        $datos[$nombre] = htmlentities($valor);

        $datos[$nombre] = html_entity_decode($datos[$nombre]); 

    }

    self::seleccionarClases($datos);
 
}

function seleccionarClases($datos){

    $json = array();
     
    $clase = new clasesModel;

    $list = $clase->getListClases($datos);
    if($list != null){
        $json['respuesta'] = $list;
        $json['msj'] = 'Se han encontado con exito las clases';
        $json['success'] = true;
    }else{
        $json['respuesta'] = $list;
        $json['msj'] = 'No se encontraron Clases';
        $json['success'] = false;
    }


    echo json_encode($json);

    
}
```

Aquí está el metodo en el modelo

```
public function getListClases($datos)
{

    require '../require/Conexion.php';

    $search = $datos["search"];

    $sql = "
    SELECT cr.id_clase, cr.id_programa, cr.id_servicio, cr.id_categoria, cr.id_subcategoria,
    cr.id_alcance,cr.id_nivel, cr.id_metas, cr.id_estatus, cr.nombre_clase, cr.descripcion,
    pg.nombre_programa, sv.nombre_servicio, cs.nombre_categoria, sc.nombre_subcategoria,
    mt.nombre_metas, nv.nombre_nivel, ac.nombre_alcance, cr.duracion_clase 
    FROM ec_clase_raiz AS cr
    INNER JOIN ec_estatus AS es ON (cr.id_estatus = es.id_estatus)
    INNER JOIN ec_programa AS pg ON (cr.id_programa = pg.id_programa)
    INNER JOIN ec_servicio AS sv ON (cr.id_servicio = sv.id_servicio)
    INNER JOIN ec_categoria_servicio AS cs ON (cr.id_categoria = cs.id_categoria)
    INNER JOIN ec_subcategoria_servicio as sc ON (cr.id_subcategoria = sc.id_subcategoria)
    INNER JOIN ec_metas AS mt ON (cr.id_metas = mt.id_metas)
    INNER JOIN ec_nivel AS nv ON (cr.id_nivel = nv.id_nivel)
    INNER JOIN ec_alcance AS ac ON (cr.id_alcance = ac.id_alcance)
    WHERE cr.nombre_clase LIKE '%$search%' 
    ORDER BY cr.nombre_clase ASC;";

    $result = @mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql); // or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    if (!$result) {
        return null;
    }
    $numeroFilas = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($numeroFilas <= 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $arreglo[] = $resultado;
        }
        return $arreglo;
    }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
}
```

**Edit:**

Hice lo que me dijeron pero ahora tengo un error con "JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data" y todavía no muestra la separación de parrafos. mostrarEditClase tiene ese problema

Si preguntan, los datos vienen asi 13 * 1 * 1 * 35

```
       function mostrarEditClase(datos){

            var d = JSON.parse(datos);
           
            $("#Id_clase").val(d[0]);

            $("#Nombre_clase").val(d[9]);

            $("#Id_programa_actual").val(d[1]);
            document.getElementById("Id_programa_actual").innerText = d[11];

            $("#Id_servicio_actual").val(d[2]);
            document.getElementById("Id_servicio_actual").innerText = d[12];

            $("#Id_categoria_actual").val(d[3]);
            document.getElementById("Id_categoria_actual").innerText = d[13];

            $("#Id_subcategoria_actual").val(d[4]);
            document.getElementById("Id_subcategoria_actual").innerText = d[14];

            $("#Id_metas_actual").val(d[7]);
            document.getElementById("Id_metas_actual").innerText = d[15];

            $("#Id_nivel_actual").val(d[6]);
            document.getElementById("Id_nivel_actual").innerText = d[16];

            $("#Id_alcance_actual").val(d[5]);
            document.getElementById("Id_alcance_actual").innerText = d[17];

            Duracion = moment.duration(d[18]).asMinutes();

            Duracion += " Minutos";

            $("#Duracion_clase_actual").val(d[9]);
            document.getElementById("Duracion_clase_actual").innerText = Duracion; 

            $("#Descripcion").val(d[10]);  
            document.getElementById("Descripcion").innerText = d[10]; 
        
            
        }
```

Comment: Dices que te sale un error de `""`, coloca todo el error

Comment: "" string literal contains an unescaped line break

Comment: Puede ser que tu párrafo tenga una comilla doble `"`, entonces cuando obtiene la información este rompe el contenido, lo que puedes hacer es usar una expresión regular que detecte si existe una comilla doble coloque una barra invertida \, el cual quedaría algo así  \".

Comment: No posee comillas dobles, se rompe si hago un espacio entre parrafos

Comment: Revisa la respuesta actualizada y, además, como primera línea de la función `mostrarEditClase(datos)` agrega `console.log(datos);` y actualiza la pregunta para mostrar el resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede ser que el error este al cerrar el contenido HTML en el JavaScript, lo que puedes hacer es usar las literales (``), estas te permiten crear texto usando variables dentro de ellas, así no tendrías que concatenarlas.

Pasarías de esto:

```
html+="<tr><td>"+valores[i][9]+"</td><td>"+valores[i][12]+"</td><td>"+valores[i][11]+"</td><td><i id='edit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editarClase' style='cursor:pointer;' onclick='mostrarEditClase("+'"'+datos+'"'+");' class='fa fa-cog' aria-hidden='true'></i></td>";
```

a estar mas legible el código:

```
html+=`<tr><td>${valores[i][12]}</td><td>${valores[i][12]}</td><td>${valores[i][11]</td><td><i id='edit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editarClase' style='cursor:pointer;' onclick="mostrarEditClase('${datos}')" class='fa fa-cog' aria-hidden='true'></i></td>`
```

Puedes consultar la documentación de las [plantillas literales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings)

Comment: Desgraciadamente eso no funcionó

Answer (score 0):

Deberías usar [JSON codificado](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify) en lugar de crear una cadena que "no puedes controlar".

Para empezar, evita el uso de `JSON.parse` y `eval()`, no son necesarios si desde que defines la petición AJAX especificas que vas a recibir la respuesta en JSON.

```
    function mostrarClases(){

        datos = { 
            "opcion"  : "mostrarClases",
            "search": $('#search').val()
            
        };
        console.log(datos);
              
        $.ajax({
            url:'../controllers/clasesController.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json', // jQuery va a convertir la respuesta en JSON
            data: datos
            
        }).done(function(response){
            // Tomas directamente los datos sin tener que "convertir"
            var data = response.respuesta;
            var msj = response.msj;
            var success = response.success; 


            html="<table class='table table-bordered table-hover'><thead><tr><td><strong>Nombre clase</strong></td><td><strong>Tipo de servicio</strong></td><td><strong>Tipo de programa</strong></td><td><strong>Editar</strong></td><td><strong>Activo</strong></td></tr></thead><tbody>";
    

            if(success){
                // No uses eval(), ya tienes un objeto JSON válido
                var valores = data;
                for(i=0; i < valores.length; i++){
                    // Guarda el objeto codificado
                    var datos = JSON.stringify(valores[i]);

                    html+="<tr><td>"+valores[i][9]+"</td><td>"+valores[i][12]+"</td><td>"+valores[i][11]+"</td><td><i id='edit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editarClase' style='cursor:pointer;' onclick='mostrarEditClase("+'"'+datos+'"'+");' class='fa fa-cog' aria-hidden='true'></i></td>";

                    if(valores[i][8] == 1){

                        html+='<td><div class="checkbox"><label style="padding-right: 30px;"><input type="checkbox" name="Estado" id="Estado'+valores[i][0]+'" onclick="cambiarEstado('+valores[i][0]+')" checked></label></div></td>';

                    }else if (valores[i][8] == 2 ){

                        html+='<td><div class="checkbox"><label style="padding-right: 30px;"><input type="checkbox" name="Estado" id="Estado'+valores[i][0]+'" onclick="cambiarEstado('+valores[i][0]+')"></label></div></td>';
                    }
                        
                }

                html+="</tbody></table>"

                $("#lista").html(html);

            }else{

                html+="<tr><td colspan='6'>"+msj+"</td></tr></tbody></table>"

                $("#lista").html(html);
            }

            $("#loader").css("display", "none");
            $("#content").css("display", "block");   
                    
        });
                
                           
    }

    function mostrarEditClase(datos){
        // Convierte el objeto codificado en JSON
        var d = JSON.parse(datos);

        // Se guardó el objeto completo
        // deberás revisar nuevamente los índices
        $("#Id_clase").val(d[0]);

        $("#Nombre_clase").val(d[9]);

        $("#Id_programa_actual").val(d[1]);
        document.getElementById("Id_programa_actual").innerText = d[11];

        $("#Id_servicio_actual").val(d[2]);
        document.getElementById("Id_servicio_actual").innerText = d[12];

        $("#Id_categoria_actual").val(d[3]);
        document.getElementById("Id_categoria_actual").innerText = d[13];

        $("#Id_subcategoria_actual").val(d[4]);
        document.getElementById("Id_subcategoria_actual").innerText = d[14];

        $("#Id_metas_actual").val(d[7]);
        document.getElementById("Id_metas_actual").innerText = d[15];

        $("#Id_nivel_actual").val(d[6]);
        document.getElementById("Id_nivel_actual").innerText = d[16];

        $("#Id_alcance_actual").val(d[5]);
        document.getElementById("Id_alcance_actual").innerText = d[17];

        Duracion = moment.duration(d[18]).asMinutes();

        Duracion += " Minutos";

        $("#Duracion_clase_actual").val(d[9]);
        document.getElementById("Duracion_clase_actual").innerText = Duracion; 

        $("#Descripcion").val(d[10]);  
    }
```

Como recomendación final, deberías usar arreglos asociativos en lugar de numéricos, porque es mucho más fácil de mantener usando `datos.nombreDeCampo` que `datos[x]`; imagina que tienes que agregar otro campo en la consulta, te obligará a revisar y (probablemente) modificar todos los índices en tus funciones Javascript.

Agrego un fragmento de código para ver que no hay problema si alguno de los datos incluye saltos de línea:

```js
// Origen de datos con saltos de línea
let response = [
  {
    0: 'Nombre',
    1: 'Dirección',
    2: `Un texto
con saltos
de línea`,
    3: 'Más info'
  }
];

let divDatos = document.querySelector('#datos');

// Codificar como cadena
let codificado = JSON.stringify(response[0]);
console.log(codificado);

document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    divDatos.innerHTML = '';
    // Obtener JSON de la cadena codificada
    let data = JSON.parse(codificado);
    console.log(data);
    let lineas = data[2].split("\n");
    lineas.forEach(linea => divDatos.innerHTML += linea + '<br>');
});
```

```html
<div id="datos">Aquí se van a mostrar los datos</div>
<button id="btn">Mostrar datos</button>
```

Comment: No funciona mostrarEditClase, sigue con el error de "" string literal contains an unescaped line break

Comment: @Shredder, por favor edita la pregunta para colocar tu código actualizado.

Comment: Buenas, coloque el código actualizado